# How to install android support repository v23.3.0 in the newest android studio version?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio version 4.0.1 (latest version) and I have a starter code of an old app and when I try to import it. it requires Android Support Repository v23.3.0 to be imported successfully and so Gradle could sync correctly but I don't know how to download this repository. is it even downloadable anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Just use in the `build.gradle` the `google` repo

```
repositories {
    google()
    //....
}
```

You can [check here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) all the versions available.

Comment: is there no way to install older versions of it?

Comment: @MohannadEl-Sayeh All the support libraries (an also the v23.x.x) are in the google repo.